# Streaming video from HTML5 to node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I have a node.js server which uses the "ws" npm package. From HTML5 I can get the users webcam stream but how do I send the webcam stream through a HTML5 websocket to my node.js server?

Currently I have this code on the server:

```
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function(data, flags) {
    console.log("Message received");
  });
});
```

And on the client this code:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

ws.onopen = function() {
  ws.send(stream);
}
```

Where the `stream` is from `navigator.getUserMedia` with `video: true`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same question... doesn't seem to be anyone who knows how...

Comment: @Costa I ended up doing a Java app that was installed on the clients, and then streamed through a regular socket to the Node.js server.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm putting together a little tutorial here: https://github.com/wamoyo/webrtc-cafe Feel free to follow along if it's useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `socket.io-stream` npm package and then use something like this after configure it (works on server and client):

```
// send data 
ss(socket).on('file', function(stream) {
  fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file').pipe(stream);
});

// receive data 
ss(socket).emit('file', stream);
stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.txt'));
```

from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream)

Comment: This way is for streaming a static file instead of live webcam